# How to parse binary data from websockets?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm trying to parse frames from Websockets.
I did it with Fiddler, which shows me binary data from the frame.
I need the same result but I need to get it via Javascript or Php (or any other language).
I tried to do that with Js

```
var a = new WebSocket("ws://example.com");   
a.onopen = function() 
 { 
  console.log("open"); 
  a.send("test");
  var b = new Uint8Array([8,6,7,5,3,0,9]);
  a.send(b.buffer); };
a.onmessage = function(e) {  console.log(e.data.toString());};
a.onclose = function() { console.log("closed");};
```

But I didn't receive any data on "a.onmessage".
At this moment I've stucked.
To clarify my question one more time.
I need simple code example which parses frames from websockets.
[Example of what I'm trying to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49LoV.png)

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean WebSocket in the browser then you're out of luck. The browser API provides only messages, not frames. Frames are a part of the underlying transport only.

Answer (score 0):

Using [DataView](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/#toc-dataview):

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8081');
socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

socket.onmessage = function (e) {
  var data = e.data;
  var dv = new DataView(data);

  // reads an UInt16 at the beginning 
  var uint16= dv.getUint16(0);

  // reads next UInt16 (sets 2 bytes of offset, since previous UInt16 takes 2 bytes)  
  var another_uint16= dv.getUint16(0);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! 
I've test your approach on websocket ws://51.254.98.30:443
But I still can't receive any data. Is your approach works for you with this websocket?
Thanks!

Comment: so `onmessage` is never called? (I fixed a little typo). Try to put a handler on `onerror` and see if something is going on.